# How to add an outline to a mask with no internal lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mask, cartopy

For a given 2D mask, I would like to draw its outline with no internal lines between adjacent grid cells. Highlighting one cell is straightforward: [How to mark cells in matplotlib.pyplot.imshow (drawing cell borders)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654952/how-to-mark-cells-in-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow-drawing-cell-borders) and highlighting many cells is also straightforward: [Python matplotlib - add borders to grid plot based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432498/python-matplotlib-add-borders-to-grid-plot-based-on-value). However, I do not want internal boundaries within the mask to be separated by a line, so the second link above is not suitable.

Here is example code to generate a mask:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 50
xbound = np.linspace(0, 10, N + 1)
ybound = np.linspace(0, 10, N + 1)
x = (xbound[:-1] + xbound[1:]) / 2
y = (ybound[:-1] + ybound[1:]) / 2

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.exp(-((X - 2.5)**2 + (Y - 2.5)**2)) + np.exp(-2 * ((X - 7.5)**2 + (Y - 6.5)**2))
mask = Z > 0.2

plt.imshow(mask, origin='lower', extent=(0, 10, 0, 10))
```

Which generates the image:

[image: Simple 2D mask]

I want the boundary to be around each of the pixelated yellow circles, and to follow the same edges as show above (i.e. be parallel to the x/y-axis) - I want to emphasize that the underlying data is gridded. Using:

```
plt.contour(x, y, mask, levels=[0.5])
```

comes close, but the contour is at 45° along the staircase edges.

Bonus points if the outline can be filled or shown using cartopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `shapely` shapes and the union operation. The idea is to create a square (or rectangle etc.) for each cell where the mask is true, then combine contiguous squares together. These geometries can then be plotted or used to create `matplotlib` polygons. The following shows the outline in red (with the staircase edge as required):

```
import shapely.geometry
import shapely.ops

geoms = []
for yidx, xidx in zip(*np.where(mask)):
    geoms.append(shapely.geometry.box(xbound[xidx], ybound[yidx], xbound[xidx+1], ybound[yidx+1]))
full_geom = shapely.ops.unary_union(geoms)

for geom in full_geom.geoms:
    plt.plot(*geom.exterior.xy, linewidth=4, color='r')
plt.imshow(mask, origin='lower', extent=(0, 10, 0, 10))
```

[image: mask with plotted outline]

It would be hard to fill each shape with a colour/pattern, so instead `matplotlib` polygons can be used:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

polygons = []
for geom in full_geom.geoms:
    p = Polygon(list(zip(*geom.exterior.xy)), closed=True, facecolor='none', edgecolor='r', linestyle='-', hatch='//', linewidth=4)
    polygons.append(p)

plt.figure()
axes = plt.gca()
for p in polygons:
    axes.add_patch(p)
plt.imshow(mask, origin='lower', extent=(0, 10, 0, 10))
```

[image: mask with outline defined by (fillable) polygons]

Finally, the raw `shapely` polygons can be added directly to a cartopy map:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
ax.add_geometries(
    full_geom.geoms,
    crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    facecolor='white',
    edgecolor='red',
    linewidth=4,
    hatch='//',
)
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, dms=True, x_inline=False, y_inline=False)
ax.set_xlim((0, 10))
ax.set_ylim((0, 10))
```

[image: mask with outline on cartopy map]